# Problems with CSS layout while using PHP include

Tags: php, html, css

I have a navigation bar at the top of my page. When I put the HTML directly into the page, there is no margin above it. But when I use an external HTML file and import it (using PHP `include`), there is a margin above it. The `margin`, and `padding` of all elements (like `body, div, ul, li`, etc.) have been initially reset to `0` as a part of global reset.

PHP (`include.php`):

```php
<body><?php include("topnav.html"); ?>
```

External menu file (`topnav.html`):

```html
<div id="top-nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item5</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item6</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#top-nav {
    height:35px;
    background:#000 url('../images/tile1.jpg') repeat-x;
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #666;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #666;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "external html menu file"? Can you reproduce this behavior on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Use tinkerbin.com to show your current code/generated code.

Comment: is there any css file or style setting in <head> of include.php? if there is it may affect topnav.html

Comment: Check if you have a BOM in the included file (search SO for that keyword).

Answer (score 0):

How are you including the external menu file? Is there any whitespace before the include? If there is, that would cause the menu to be offset to allow room for the empty text node generated by the whitespace. To fix, just remove any whitespace before the include.

Comment: This is how it goes in my index.php:

<body>
<?php include("topnav.html"); ?>

There are no white spaces

Comment: Well in the part you just gabe me there, you have a space between `<body>` and `<?php` - remove that and it should work.

Comment: Tried that already, but no success. But your answer seems relevant as I changed the font size and the space above the nav-bar increased. I already tried optimizers to remove whitespaces from both my index.php and the external menu file, but still no success

Comment: White space before the div wouldn't do this.

Comment: Have you tried using the Developer Tools of your browser? You should be able to see from there if the navigation bar really is the first child of the body, or if there's a text node hiding in there somewhere.